# Get strings between different tags in xml

Tags: python

```
text='<tag1>one</tag1>this should be displayed<tag2>two</tag2>this too<tag3>three</tag3>and this<tag4>four</tag4>'
```

Consider this string, using python
I want to print :

```
this should be displayed
this too
and this
```

not

```
one,two,three,four
```

I tried this code:

```
import re

text='<>one</>this should be displayed<>two</>this too<>three</>and this<>four</>'
start=0
m=re.findall('>(.+?)<',text)

print m
```

but I am getting all the strings:

```
['one', 'this should be displayed', 'two', 'this too', 'three', 'and this', 'four']
```

Comment: you may consider accepting an answer that helped you understand and solve your problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it, just need a `/`, Notice that you only want the words between `/>` and `<` not `>` and `<`:

**Change this**:

```
m=re.findall('>(.+?)<',text)
```

**to this**:

```
m=re.findall('/>(.+?)<',text)
```

**Hence**:

```
import re

text='<>one</>this should be displayed<>two</>this too<>three</>and this<>four</>'
print(re.findall('/>(.+?)<',text))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['this should be displayed', 'this too', 'and this']
```

**EDIT**:

Using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4

text='<tag1>one</tag1>this should be displayed<tag2>two</tag2>this too<tag3>three</tag3>and this<tag4>four</tag4>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
for elem in soup:
    if type(elem) is bs4.element.NavigableString:  # only if the elem is not of a tag type
       print(elem)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
this should be displayed
this too
and this
```

Comment: Thank you. But in xml we have tag name inside. like <tagname>one</tagname>. so I can't use ('/>(.+?)<')

Comment: @ShruthiG try escaping it with `\/>`. Also if you are parsing an xml, I would suggest to opt for `lxml` or `beautifulSoup`

Answer (score 1):

Need to add a forward slash in the first part of the match, also I would use `([^<]+?)` – i think that's probably just semantics at this point, though, unless your input isn't correctly formatted.

`m=re.findall('\/>([^<]+?)<',text)`

And you just changed your question, so here's a new answer to find text outside of tags:

`m=re.findall('</.+?>([^<]+?)<.+?>',text)`

Comment: Woa!. I am getting the right output. Thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: If xml has nested tags like:

text='<tag1>one<innertag1></innertag1><innertag2></innertag2></tag1>this should be displayed<tag2>two</tag2>this too<tag3>three</tag3>and this<tag4>four</tag4>'

I need to print "one"

Comment: how to get string preceded by '>' should be followed by only '<' but not followed by '</' ?

Comment: `m=re.findall('<.+?>([^<]+?)<[\d\w]+?>',text)` – `[\d\w]+?`will match any alphanumerical character, but not `/`